# Update the date fields from the values returned from a subquery Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an application that scans a table for IDs that do not have a processed date. When an ID is processed, a process date is added to Table 1 and the entire record is copied to another table (table 2) if it completes the application.

I need to compare IDs in the tables looking for IDs from table 1 that are not in table 2 but has a date for when it was processed. This is a sign that the id was processed but never made it to the end of the application and failed along the way.

I then need to update these IDs (records) from table 1 by setting the processing date to null so the application picks it up in the next run.

Here is a query that gets the IDs I need.

```
SELECT Subject_Number 
From Table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                    FROM Table2 
                    WHERE Table2.Subject_Number = Table1.Subject_Number)
AND Table1.Processed_Date IS NOT NULL.
```

Now I just need to update the processed date to null for the IDs this returns.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query something like this

```
UPDATE <table> SET <fields> WHERE <table.id> IN (
  SELECT Subject_Number 
  From Table1 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL 
    FROM Table2 
      WHERE Table2.Subject_Number = Table1.Subject_Number) 
        AND Table1.Processed_Date IS NOT NULL.)
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! The query I attempted just off the mark. The query you provided works great!